# Initiate a WebView rotation on Android

Tags: android

I have a application with a WebView, most of the time it stays portrait mode, but but certain time, I want to force to landscape mode, for example, for image display. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go step-by-step:

1. Detect whether the resource which is about to be loaded in the `WebView` is an image or not. The easiest way to do so is just checking the URL extension by setting a `WebViewClient` and overriding the `onPageStarted` method. Of course, this is not completely reliable since the URL for images sometimes does not have an extension.
2. Once you know whether the resource is an image or not, you can use the `setRequestedOrientation` method of the `Activity` class:

---

```
if( is an image ) {
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
} else {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how to get the orientation: upsidedown portrait and revers landscape?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Could you rephrase, please?

Comment: By default, the landscape is to rotate the phone clockwise 90 degrees, how to get 270 degrees?

Comment: Seems like I need to listent to the SensorEvent to do this.

Comment: Not sure if that's possible. Standard activities only support 90 degrees rotations.